# Summing duplicate rows in DataTable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a CSV-file that looks something like this:

```
19177;string1;
10017;string2;6765,00
10017;string2;240,00
10238;string3;350,00
10238;string3;750,00
10238;string3;60170,00
10238;string3;1035,00
```

I have been able to put this into a DataTable using vb.net. Now I want to group duplicates together using column number 1 + 2 and summing column number 3 so I can generate a new CSV-file that looks like this:

```
19177;string1;
10017;string2;7005,00
10238;string3;62305,00
```

I have searched a lot and found that I can probably use something called LINQ, but is there a way to just do this in pure vb.net? I can't seem to grasp the concept of how to go about this.

EDIT:

I was hoping to avoid LINQ, so using a for each statement seems like something I should be able to manage. Would something like this be a good start or am I on the totally wrong foot here?

```
For Each r As DataRow In mytable.Rows
    For Each item In r.ItemArray
        Do something
    Next
Next
```

I feel I am in the wrong "layer" here of sorts, and I struggle to conceptualize this in my head enough to get it out in code. I would need to compare whole rows, not just individual items like this does.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried first, then we can help.

Comment: To be quite frank I have not tried much yet, because I don't see how to approach the problem. I don't know enough about DataTable to know where to start, and I have searched without finding anything in vb.net that helps me. If you could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Comment: Ok, you can use LINQ, Excel interop, for each statement, etc. There are ***many ways*** to do this. Heres one of those https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1239768/Get-sum-of-required-values-in-datatable-VB-NET

Comment: I was hoping to avoid LINQ - added some more information to the question to explain where I am at codewise and skillwise.

Comment: It's a start for sure. You would need to loop each row in that DataTable. You then would need to get a distinct list of your column, per say "id". Next you would sum up each distinct value by looping the table again looking for each value...

Comment: `To be quite frank I have not tried much yet`  Then this post is premature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is using linq. If you would like to avoid using linq, you can, but you need to write much more lines of code. Anyhow, here is an example which shows how to use linq to group the rows based on first two columns and then calculate sum of 3rd column.

Let's say input data table contains C1(Inetegr), C2(String), C3(Integer) columns which you load from CSV file:

```
C1   | C2   | C3    
-------------------
1    |One   | 100
1    |One   | 200
2    |Two   | 300
2    |Two   | 400
3    |Three | 500
```

Just for test purpose, let's say, this is the data table:

```
Dim dt = New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("C1", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("C2", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("C3", GetType(Integer))
dt.Rows.Add(1, "One", 100)
dt.Rows.Add(1, "One", 200)
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Two", 300)
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Two", 400)
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Three", 500)
```

To get the expected result, you can use the following code:

```
Dim q = From r In dt.AsEnumerable()
        Select C1 = r.Field(Of Integer)("C1"),
                C2 = r.Field(Of String)("C2"),
                C3 = r.Field(Of Integer)("C3")
        Group By C1, C2 Into Group
        Select C1, C2, C3 = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.C3)
Dim result = dt.Clone()
For Each item In q
    result.Rows.Add(item.C1, item.C2, item.C3)
Next
```

And the result would be:

```
C1   | C2   | C3    
-------------------
1    |One   | 300
2    |Two   | 700
3    |Three | 500
```

Comment: I can't get this to work because C3 is not an integer. I have tried converting it to double and inserting "Of Double", but it won't work because my conversions to double does not work.

Comment: If you just copy and paste what I wrote in the answer, you will see it's a working solution. What you are asking in comments is not about what you asked in question. In the question you are asking about group by and sum. But in this comment you are asking how to read the CSV file to a data table having int, string and double columns.

Comment: Anyhow, to convert a string field to double, you need `Double.Parse(r.Field(Of string)("C3"))`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. I had a lot of mistakes in my code before your code ran, and have fixed those now.